# Implementation of the replacing game scene in C++

Tags: c++, scene

I have about 10 scene classes in my C++ game. It's something like a regular game screen (menu screen, game screen, leaderboard, options, etc). So I need some technique to replace one scene to another. I've read all comments you posted me in this thread and tried to implement it. Now I have following code:

```
// -----[ main.cpp ]----- //
#include "SceneManager.h"
#include "Scene.h"

int main( int argc, const char * argv[] ) {
    SceneManager *sceneManager = new SceneManager();
    sceneManager->changeScene( 0 );
    delete sceneManager;
    return 0;   
}

// -----[ Scene.h ]----- //
class SceneManager;
class Scene {
public:
    SceneManager *sceneManager;
    void start( SceneManager *sceneManager );
};

// -----[ SceneManager.h ]----- //
#include "Scene.h"
#include "MenuScene.h"
#include "GameScene.h"

class Scene;
class MenuScene;
class GameScene;

class SceneManager {
public:
    Scene* scene;

    void changeScene( short id ) {

        if ( scene != NULL ) {
            delete scene; // to prevent a memory leak
        }

        if ( id == 0 ) {
            scene = new MenuScene();
        } else if ( id == 1 ) {
            scene = new GameScene();
        }

        if (scene) {
            scene->start( this );
        }
    }
};


// -----[ MenuScene.h ]----- //
class MenuScene: public Scene {
public:
    void start( SceneManager *sceneManager ) {
        this->sceneManager = sceneManager;
    }
};

// -----[ GameScene.h ]----- //
class GameScene: public Scene {
public:
    void start( SceneManager *sceneManager ) {
        this->sceneManager = sceneManager;
    }
};
```

It doesn't work because of error (XCode 4.6, MacOS X):

```
Apple Match-O Linker (id) Error
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Scene::start(SceneManager*)", referenced from:
      SceneManager::changeScene(short) in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

What do i do wrong? How to fix it? Maybe someone knows about some popular issues on this subject?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking but it's common to have a base class and inherit each scene class from it.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I don't know how can I call a function from the parent class. Do I need to create child classes based on the base class? Do I need forward declaration here or I can do without it? I can't imagine how to design this scheme without a forward declaration.

Comment: `MenuScene` and `GameScene` are not scene managers, so they should not be subclasses of `SceneManager`. There should be a `Scene` parent class from which they inherit.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for that correction. I've renamed my class from SceneManager to Scene.

Comment: But now you have a class `Scene` that's acting as a scene manager. That is the job of another class. What I'm trying to say is that this design needs one more class. One to be a scene manager, one to be a base scene class, and then one for each of your scene types.

Comment: @Stephen, Can you please provide your words with a code? I don't understand your structure but I suppose it might be very interesting issue :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, I believe your design conceptually needs another class. Here is a rough example.

```
class Scene {
public:
    virtual void start() = 0;
};

class SceneManager {
public:
    void changeScene( short id ) {

        Scene* scene = NULL;
        if ( id == 0 ) {
            scene = new MenuScene(); // undeclared yet
        } else if ( id == 1 ) {
            scene = new GameScene(); // undeclared yet
        }

        if (scene) {
            // TODO: make the scene visible.
            scene->start();
        }
    }
};

class MenuScene: public Scene {
public:
    virtual void start() {
        // Draw menu stuff
    }
};

class GameScene: public Scene {
public:
    void start() {
        // Draw game stuff
    }
};
```

It's hard to be more specific than that without knowing more context about your particular environment.

Comment: This is a very interesting issue! But how can I call changeScene() from the GameScene or the MenuScene classes? I need to changeScene from the GameScene or MenuScene I think I don't have such option here? :)

Comment: Asking to my question by myself: you need to store a link in the classes: MenuScene/GameScene which will be point to SceneManager class.